# mysql order by inner query field

Tags: mysql, subquery

my query is:

```
select a from b where c in (
    select d from e where f in (
        select f from e where d=100)
    and e!=100 group by e order by count(e) desc
   )
)
```

this query will output result what i want but I want to order it by this subquery

```
select d from e where f in (
    select f from e where d=100)
and e!=100 group by e order by count(f) desc
```

basically I want to order by count(f)

how can I achieve that main query take ids from subquery but it will not order them according subquery

Answer (score 1):

Taking from the SQL you added, I derived something like this:

```
    SELECT e1.d
  FROM e e1,
       (SELECT *
          FROM e
         WHERE d = 100) e2
 WHERE e1.f = e2.f AND e1.e != 100
GROUP BY e1.e
ORDER BY COUNT (e2.f)
```